# Loop and search for values in Delphi TStack<T>

Tags: delphi, stack

I have a `TStack<string>` and I need loop all items searching for a value without remove the item of the stack. I have `Pop` and `Extract` methods but they remove the items from stack.

How could I loop all items of the stack and check for a specific value without remove it?

```
 procedure test;
 var
   i: integer;
 begin
   Stack := TStack<String>.Create;

   { Push some items to the stack. }
   Stack.Push('John');
   Stack.Push('Mary');
   Stack.Push('Bob');
   Stack.Push('Anna');
   Stack.Push('Erica');

   for i:=0 to Stack.Count -1 do begin
     item := Stack.Peek; --->How to do it
     if item = 'Bob' then dosomething; ----->Here is the problem
   end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find that some of your code has to iterate over a stack, maybe the `TStack<T>` doesn't represent the best choiche for that kind of data.

In any case, the underlying elements can be obtained as a `TArray<T>`.

Declare a new variable:

```
var
  arr: TArray<string>;
```

Use the [`ToArray`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Generics.Collections.TStack.ToArray) method of the `TStack<T>` object.

```
arr := Stack.ToArray;
```

Iterate over the `arr` array.

```
for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do
  item := arr[i];
```

You can also iterate directly with the `for..in` construct as pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554052/loop-and-search-for-values-in-delphi-tstackt/35554206#comment58797749_35554206) since `TStack<T>` implements `TEnumerable<T>`.

```
for item in Stack do
  . . .
```

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to consider to use a `TList<string>`. Using `Add` and `Extract(First)` you can achieve the same functionality as a stack.

Comment: Sorry, I need undo funcionallity as well. Then I choiced Tstack and I can use Push and Pop

Comment: Or use the enumerator. No time to expand on that now, but a simple `for S in Stack` should find all items in the stack.

Comment: Great  solution, Mr Rudy